# Aurelia inject inconsistency?

Tags: aurelia

If I inject the modules with one inject statement, it works.
If I inject the modules with three inject statements then, the app does not load.

I would expect that both ways are equivalent.

```
    import {AuthService} from 'aurelia-auth';
    import {bindable, inject, Aurelia} from 'aurelia-framework';
    import {ValidationControllerFactory, ValidationController, ValidationRules} from 'aurelia-validation';
    import {BootstrapFormRenderer} from './bootstrap-form-renderer';

    //Works
    //@inject(Aurelia, AuthService, ValidationControllerFactory)

    //Does not work
    @inject(Aurelia)
    @inject(AuthService)
    @inject(ValidationControllerFactory)

    export class Login {
      constructor(aurelia, authService, controllerFactory) {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple calls to the `inject` decorator won't work due to how the decorator is implemented. What the inject decorator does is create the static inject() function on the class. So multiple calls to the inject decorator will just keep overwriting the static inject property.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `static inject()` for multiple injects like that:

```
export class SampleModel {

    static inject() { return [DatabaseService, AuthService, EventAggregator]; }

    constructor(db, auth, events){
      this.db = db;
      this.auth = auth;
      this.events = events;
    }
}
```

You can read more info about dependency injection in aurelia cheat shit: http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/cheat-sheet/3

Comment: Ok thanks, so the multiple injects are old style. Is there a documentation link that states that a single inject is the way to go?

Comment: @user905374, you can read about injection in aurelia cheat shit: http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/cheat-sheet/3

Comment: Multiple `inject` decorators aren't "old style," they've never worked. What the `inject` decorator does is create the `static inject()` function on the class. So multiple calls to the `inject` decorator will just keep overwriting the `static inject` property.

Comment: @AshleyGrant Great that's what I was looking for. If you add your comment as an answer I will accept it.